# Exit search view

Tags: objective-c

I am very new to objective-c.

I have a view that consists of a search bar and below it a table view.
When the user searches, an array is created from a server side XML file.
Everything works fine, but when the user presses the search button the table view still shows the previous data until the cancel button is pressed.

How do I mimic the action of the cancel button, when the user presses the search button to return from the "search view" to the main table view?

searchBarSearchButtonClicked:

```
NSString * path2 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://URL/%@.xml", self.mySearchBar.text];
[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path2];
[self.mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

I tried using self.mySearchBar resignFirstResponder, but that just hides the keyboard, the user is still in the "search view".

Comment: How have you hooked up the search view to the main table view?

Comment: In the header file: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *mySearchBar;

Comment: Should have been more specific.   How are you communicating to the main view to do something with the data in the search bar.   And to that end, when you say "return from the search view", I've been assuming you mean remove filters, are you talking about something else?   It's not very clear.

Comment: I am sorry my question is not clear. I did not do anything to communicate with the main view, it is the default searchbar behaviour. When the user presses the search bar the view changes automatically. I have manage to be clear, again I apologise but I am very new to objective-c and xcode

Comment: Are you using the same button for cancel and search? (i.e. will `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` be called both times?  Normally, if you're canceling out of a search you need to manually reset the contents that are used by the main view.  Further, you might need to hide the search view if desired.

Comment: What happens at the moment is when the user clicks the search button, a request is made to a XML file on the server using the search bar text as a parameter. The XML file is then parsed and once the parserDidEndDocument is called it reloads the data: [newsTable reloadData];. When I press the cancel button it returns to the main table view with the updated data. The problem is that it only shows the main tale view if the cancel button is pressed. I want to return to the main table view when the search button is pressed.

Comment: Are you pushing the `UISearchBar` or is it just appearing on that current page? If you are pushing to get to the `UISearchBar`, then you'll want to pop the view with the parent NSViewController in order to get back.  Or am I misinterpreting again?

Comment: If i understand correctly what you mean by "pushing" I am not pushing the search bar. My main view consists of the search bar and table view. Maybe I am abusing the search bar and should just use a text input with a button that pulls the XML and reloads the table data?

Comment: I'm still a bit mystified as to exactly what's going on, but a UISearchBar should be fine for this use.   Assuming your main view has a `UITableView` in it, is the `UITableView` getting sent a `-reloadData` message after the XML is loaded?

Comment: Yes it is. I have a few methods that parse the XML document into an Array. Once the parsing has completed I reload the data.

Comment: thank you for your time in trying to help, but the suggested code below solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Where should I add this? (sorry but I am new and learning)

Comment: After you resignFirstResponder.